# How to deserialize Json with a nested array of objects in a simple Spring Boot application

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, http-post

The Json POST request looks like this:

```
   {
   'title':'Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back',
   'description':'Darth Vader is adamant about turning Luke Skywalker to the dark side.',
   'actors':[
      {
         'lastName':'Ford',
         'name':'Harrison'
      },
      {
         'lastName':'Hamill',
         'name':'Mark'
      }
   ]
  }
```

So my Spring Boot Application just wants to store this whole json as a "Film" class and inside it has an inline array of "Actors". Here is the Film model:

```
    @Entity
    public class Film {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
      private long id;
      private String title;
      private String description;
    
      private ArrayList<Actor> actors = new ArrayList<>();
```

I have a separate entity for the Actor that looks similar:

```
    @Entity
    public class Actor {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue
      private long id;
      private String name;
      private String lastName;
```

Finally, I am using the RequestBody Annotation in the PostMapping in the Controller:

```
    @PostMapping(value= "/api/film")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Film addFilm(@RequestBody Film film) {
       service.createFilm(film);
       return film;
```

The problem is I always get the java.io.NotSerializableException that Actor cannot be serialized. I tried making Actor a Static inline class but that did not change anything. Anyone have an idea what is wrong here ?

Comment: Have you tried giving any relationship between Film and Actor?

Comment: Well Film contains a List of Actors. In response I want same thing as my request except with a unique ID generated for each Film or Actor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Actor class needs to implement Serializable.

```
@Entity
public class Actor implements Serializable{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;
  private String name;
  private String lastName;
```

Comment: Thanks this actually got rid of the error! Only thing is in response id for Actor is always 0. Any idea why it does not get auto generated like how the Film does ?

Comment: Actually Figured it out, thanks adding Serializable fixed everything.